# Is there a Universal Voxel Translator available?

Tags: voxel

Is there a simple program anywhere than knows how to translate from voxel type A to voxel type B.  I don't want to buy a Voxel editor,  I just want to translate some voxels the same way I'd translate from BMP to JPG or PNG to GIF.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  There is a free fair source Universal Voxel project named UVOX.

You can find it here:
http://tox.land/uvox/

Their project goal is to support ALL voxel formats.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project I am working on: vengi-voxconvert - which aims to be like ffmpeg or imagemagicks - but for voxels. Find the source here: https://github.com/vengi-voxel/vengi

It can read and write to more than 30 different formats